Joining two tables with a joint result in Postgresql
There are two tables.
table1
select tt1.*
    from 
    (values(1,'key1',5),(2,'key1',6),(3,'key1',7)
    ) as tt1(id, field2,field3)

table2
select tt2.*
from 
(values(4,'key1',null),(2,'key1',null),(3,'key1',null)) as tt2(id, field2,field3)

How can I combine these two tables in a query to get the result like this?
select tt2.*
from 
(values(1,'key1',5),(2,'key1',6),(3,'key1',7),(4,'key1',null)) as tt2(id,field2,field3)


with a FULL OUTER JOIN on the tables' respective id or id, field2 and some COALESCE

Need a better example. What if tt2.field3 and tt1.field3 are both not NULL for the same key?

Do a full join (or full outer join) on the id column and use coalesce to merge the columns from the two tables:
with
tt1 (id, field2, field3) as (
    select * from (values(1, 'key1', 5), (2, 'key1', 6), (3, 'key1', 7))
),
tt2 (id, field2, field3) as (
    select * from (values(4, 'key1', null::integer), (2, 'key1', null), (3, 'key1', null))
)
select
    coalesce(tt1.id, tt2.id) as id,
    coalesce(tt1.field2, tt2.field2) as field2,
    coalesce(tt1.field3, tt2.field3) as field3
from
    tt1
full join tt2 using (id);

Output:
 id | field2 | field3
----+--------+--------
  1 | key1   |      5
  2 | key1   |      6
  3 | key1   |      7
  4 | key1   |
(4 rows)

Note that if there are different non-null values in tt1 and tt2, with this coalesce call, tt1 values will be chosen.

I think you need this SQL query:
SELECT id, field2, field3
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, field2, field3
FROM table2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1);


Use UNION ALL for a better performance

That won't give the result desired by OP.
